# How can I extend class Confide in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I want to extend/overwrite the method `logAttempt` in class `Confide` ([Confide on GitHub](https://github.com/Zizaco/confide)) in order to execute some extra code whenever someone logs in successfully. This would be cleaner than copying the same code to all controllers where `logAttempt` is called.

I read through the Laravel documentation and several answers here on stackoverflow, but I just can't get it working.

I created a new folder `app/extensions` with a file named `Confide.php`:

```
<?php

namespace Extensions;

class Confide extends \Zizaco\Confide\Confide {

    public function __construct(ConfideRepository $repo) {
        die('no way!');
        $this->repo = $repo;
        $this->app = app();
    }

    public function logAttempt($credentials, $confirmed_only = false, $identity_columns = array()) {
        die('yeah man!');
    }
}
```

I added the directory to my `app/start/global.php`:

```
ClassLoader::addDirectories(array(
    // ...
    app_path().'/extensions',
));
```

I also added it to `composer.json` and ran `composer dump-autoload`:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...,
        "app/extensions"
    ]
},
```

My own `Confide` class seems not to be loaded at all, because Confide works as normal – without ever `die()`-ing.

And if I use `\Extensions\Confide::logAttempt($input, true);` in my controller including the namespace, I get this ErrorException:

> Non-static method Extensions\Confide::logAttempt() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Do I really need my own `ConfideServiceProvider` class as well? I tried that, too, but I'm not sure at all what to put in there to make Confide use my extended class.

Is there no simple way to extend a tiny bit of a class? There must be, I'm just missing something here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking to execute some code when a user logs in, you should just listen for that event.  In this case, I believe Confide uses the Auth class to login, so you should be able to listen for that event.

```
Event::listen('auth.login', function($user)
{
    $user->last_login = new DateTime;
    $user->save();
});
```

I find this much easier and cleaner than worrying about extending classes.

Comment: I was actually searching for an event where I could hook into, but didn't find anything. I'll try it later and if it works that would be indeed cleaner.

Comment: This is my accepted answer, because it solved my actual problem in a much easier way, although I asked for a different solution, because I didn't know better. It works and I'm using this, just with an own class as listener (as described here: http://four.laravel.com/docs/events#using-classes-as-listeners)

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: Made a mistake

I think you need to call the method like this:

```
\Extensions\Confide->logAttempt($input, true);
```

because you are using:

```
\Extensions\Confide::logAttempt($input, true);
```

Which is how you call static methods.

Comment: Thanks, but this unfortunately doesn't work. I don't have an instance of `Confide` in my controller. This is indeed a bit confusing. The original code (which works) is `if (Confide::logAttempt($input, true)) {...}`, while the original method `logAttempt` is actually not static (https://github.com/Zizaco/confide/blob/master/src/Zizaco/Confide/Confide.php).

Comment: Ok it seems as though laravel 4 uses some magic under the hood to make it look as though u are using a static methods when you actually are not. I only other thing you might need to do is add it to the aliases list in app/config/app.php, if you are using one for confide in there already make it the namespace point at the one in the Extensions directory.

Comment: Then just just access the confide extended class by using the alias

Comment: Hmm, the alias `Confide` points to `Zizaco\Confide\ConfideFacade`. To be honest I don't want to extend that as well... :( But after extending ConfideServiceProvider it finally seems to work more or less. The only problem, within my extended `logAttempt` method I'm unable to use any other standard Laravel stuff like `Log`, `Session` or whatever, because then I get an expeption like *"Class 'Extensions\Log' not found"* and `\Illuminate\Log` doesn't exist either. I find it all a bit frustrating. I might just create a helper function instead of trying to extend Confide.

Comment: I just figured out that I have just have to add one backslash, e.g. `\Log`.

Comment: ok np, sorry i couldn't be more help I'm just starting to learn more about laravel 4 myself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42957/discussion-between-nic-and-micb)

Answer (score 0):

I think I finally figured it out.

I had to extend `ConfideServiceProvider` as well like so:

```
<?php

namespace Extensions;

class ConfideServiceProvider extends \Zizaco\Confide\ConfideServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Bootstrap the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot() {
        $this->package('extensions/confide');
    }

    /**
     * Register the application bindings.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function registerConfide() {
        $this->app->bind('confide', function($app) {
            return new Confide($app->make('confide.repository'));
        });
    }

}
```

The code above goes into `app/extensions/ConfideServiceProvider.php`. Note: In `boot()` I replaced "zizaco" with "extensions" and in `registerConfide()` I made no changes at all, but if this method is not present in the extended class, the original class will be used. I've got no idea why.

Then in `app/config/app.php` I replaced `Zizaco\Confide\ConfideServiceProvider` with `Extensions\ConfideServiceProvider`.

My own extended `Confide` class looks like this now:

```
<?php

namespace Extensions;

class Confide extends \Zizaco\Confide\Confide {

    public function logAttempt($credentials, $confirmed_only = false, $identity_columns = array()) {
        $result = parent::logAttempt($credentials, $confirmed_only, $identity_columns);
        if ($result) {
            // Login successful. Do some additional stuff.
            \Log::info('User ' . \Auth::user()->username . ' logged in.');
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Note: If you want to use any other standard Laravel class like `Log`, `Session` etc., prefix it with one backslash as shown in the example above, or add a `use` operator for each class you use (e.g. `use \Log;`).